# Is it possible implement Pregel in Erlang without supersteps?

Tags: erlang, parallel-processing, erlang-otp

Let's say we implement [Pregel](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/06/large-scale-graph-computing-at-google.html) with Erlang. Why do we actually need supersteps? Isn't it better to just send messages from one supervisor to processes that represent nodes? They could just apply the calculation function to themselves, send messages to each other and then send a 'done' message to the supervisor.

What is the whole purpose of supersteps in concurrent Erlang implementation of Pregel?

Comment: hey martin.. i wasnt able to reply to ur comment on my blog for some reason.

Comment: hey, Arun... I will wait for the reply on your blog.

Comment: Kindly delete the phoebus folder and reclone it from git afresh. Make sure you have downloaded the rebar executable and it is available in your PATH. The "generate" should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The SuperStep concept as espoused by the Pregel model could be viewed as sort of a Barrier for parallel-y executing entities. At the end of each superstep, each worker, flushes it state to the persistent store.
- The algorithm is check-pointed at the end of each SuperStep so that in case of failure, when a new node has to take over the function of a failed peer, it has a point to start from. Pregel guarantees that since the data of the node has been flushed to disk before the SuperStep started, it can reliably start from exactly that point.
- It also in a way signifies "progress" of the algorithm. A pregel algorithm/job can be provided with a "max number of supersteps" after which the algorithm should terminate.

What you specified in your question (about superisors sending worker a calculation function and waiting for a "done") can definitely be implemented (although I dont think the current supervisor packaged with OTP can do stuff like that out of the box) but I guess the concept of a SuperStep is just a requirement of a Pregel model. If on the other hand, you were implementing something like a parallel mapper (like what Joe implements in his book) you wont need supersteps/